# solr indexing for more than one entity

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using Solr for indexing in my Java Web Project. I have read the tutorials for Solr and got some basic regarding it. There is an XML file schema.xml, in which the fields to be indexed are given in the field tag. My questions are:

1. I have the fields in an XML file present in DB, is it possible to for schema.xml file to refer the XML data present in DB.
2. If not then I will have to put all the fields in the schema.xml, so if such is a case then if there is more than one entity that has to be indexed, should they all be put in the same schema.xml or can we create a different XML files for each entity?

Comment: do you have an xml file with the data in the database as a blob and you want to index that data ?

Comment: @Jayendra yes, the data in the database is as a blob and i want to index it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the following approach :-

You can use [DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) to index the entities

Use the combination of [XPathEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#XPathEntityProcessor) to read the blob file and apply xpath on the xml file to generate fields.

Some thing like this and you can search and expand further .....

```
<entity name='test' query='select blob from table' dataSource='db'>
    <field column='blob' />
    <entity name='parse_xpath' dataSource='<FieldReaderDataSource>' processor='XPathEntityProcessor' forEach='/root' dataField='test.blob'>
        <field column='some_element' xpath='/some_element' />
    </entity>
</entity>
```

You have to have the fields defined in the schema.xml for each mapping you are specifying in the DIH config and the xml file.
It would not create them automatically unless you are using [dynamic fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields).

```
<dynamicField indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="*" stored="true" type="text_en"/>
```

Comment: is it necessary to define the fields in schema.xml ?

Comment: If you want to search and display the fields, you would need to define the fields. You can also define a catch all field then you dont need to define these fields.

Comment: Do u have any link so that i can refer to how to define it. And after defining the catch all field, can the fields be searched and displayed ? And thanks for the help it is really helpful for me.

Comment: I added a sample of the field defination with the answer. If you mark it as stored and indexed they would be available for search and display.

Comment: What if i add data to solr like this :-

`SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://HOST:8983/solr/");
 SolrInputDocument doc1 = new SolrInputDocument();
    doc1.addField( "id",1.0f );
    doc1.addField( "name", "abc" );
    doc1.addField( "price", 10 );
 SolrInputDocument doc2 = new SolrInputDocument();
    doc2.addField( "id", 1 );
    doc2.addField( "rollno", 10 );
    doc2.addField( "address", "xyz" );
 Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
    docs.add( doc1 );
    docs.add( doc2 );
server.add( docs );`

Comment: doc1 is for one entity and doc2 is for another entity. And using the catch all field. So there will be two documents on the solr server. So when i search by a query say " rollno : 10 ", will it search in both the documents or just the one containing the field.

Comment: It will search all the documents but will return only those which match the query.